# php,fileopen and read and write in url

Tags: php

i am open a image in html and i would like to resize it's size by typing in url like localhost/changimage.php?width=40

Here is my code to open file and read the image:changimage.php

```
<?php

$remoteImage = "/var/www/html/zahir/images/bike.jpeg";

$imginfo = getimagesize($remoteImage);

header("Content-type: ".$imginfo['mime']);
//header("Content-Length

readfile($remoteImage);


?>
```

I have no idea how to do it..

Comment: You'd best be looking up a tutorial on how to use the GD Library, which allows you to do image resizing, and much more in PHP.

Comment: Use imagecopyresampled function in GD Library to resize the image